# x86 assembly: How do I test if a value is even? (Extreme beginner)

Tags: assembly, x86, sequence, masm, fibonacci

I am trying to fill an array with values of the Fibonacci sequence. The line that I am having trouble with is one in which I am trying to determine whether or not the requested Fibonacci number is even. Something like modulus would possibly make sense.. I have been searching the web and am unable to find the solution. Also if any one could provide pointers on other places I may be going wrong in the code, it would be much appreciated as I have tried but I have no doubt there are other mistakes.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall 
.stack 4096
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode: DWORD

.data
array DWORD size DUP 3 (99h)

.code
main PROC 
mov eax, 0          
mov ecx, 1           

L1: 
sub ebx, 2
cmp ebx, 0 
jz Finish
add eax + ecx
add ecx + eax
LOOP L1


FINISH
;If eax and 1 is false jump to finish even need help here
mov edx, eax
ret    

FINISHEVEN
mov edx, ecx
ret

call DumpMem

INVOKE ExitProcess, 0 
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: You can isolate the lowest bit since that signals if a number is even or odd in binary. E.g. use `and foo, 1`.

Comment: And if you don't want to destroy the value you're checking, you can use `test` instead of `and`.

Comment: Unrelated to your specific question: Your loop looks super broken; the (slow) `loop` instruction is like `dec ecx`/`jnz` so it's going to modify the registers you're using to accumulate Fib(n).  Also, `add eax + ecx` isn't value MASM syntax; I assume you mean `add eax, ecx`.

Comment: I got good results with google for `site:stackoverflow.com x86 even number`.

Answer (score 2):

The hint is already in your comment: you want to see whether `eax` AND 1 is zero or not.

You could do

```
and eax, 1
jz FINISHEVEN
```

However, then the value in `eax` will be the result of the logical AND, and based on your code you want to have the return value in `edx`.  So you would want to `mov edx, eax` before this code.

Another way is to use the `test` instruction, which is like `and` except that it discards the result of the logical AND, leaving the original registers unchanged and only setting the flags.  Then you could do

```
test eax, 1
jz FINISHEVEN
mov edx, eax
ret
```